# Restore site collection permission setting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-list

In my SharePoint site collection **(SharePoint Online)**, i mistakenly executed below code and it has messed up all the permissions, how to restore default set of permissions ?

```
   var web = context.get_web();
   if (!web.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments()) {
         web.breakRoleInheritance(true, false);
    }
```

Comment: did you check the site, if it just stop the inheritance and  did not remove the user? if usres are over their just simply click on delete unique permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can **reset the role inheritance** by using this code below :

```
var web = context.get_web();
   if (web.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments()) {
         web.resetRoleInheritance();
    }
```